# add active caption class to current caption

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this fiddle, and modified it a bit (added controls and pager). Now when you click on prev/next or on pager(1,2,3,etc.) I want to add active class to the current caption.

[here is a fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gepME/53/)

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        captions: false,
        controls: true,
        pager: true,
        auto: true,
        speed: 1000,
        onSlideBefore: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
            console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject);
            $('.active-caption').removeClass('active-caption');
            $(currentSlideHtmlObject).prev().addClass('active-caption')
        },
        onSlideNext: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
            console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject);
            $('.active-caption').removeClass('active-caption');
            $(currentSlideHtmlObject).next().addClass('active-caption')
        },
        onSliderLoad: function () {
            $('#bxsliderCaption>ul>li').eq(0).addClass('active-caption')
       },

        // http://bxslider.com/options 

    });
```

Comment: What did you try? Or what is you actuall problem?

Comment: my problem is that when you click on next and prev it doesn't add active class to caption @fubbe

Comment: for example here http://jsfiddle.net/gepME/54/ I added active class to the first item, want when click next or prev it pass active class to current item @fubbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this will make the active caption change automatically when the slider changes either by itself or when the user clicks prev/next or one of the numbers on the pager.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var myCount = 1;
var backwardsCount = 2;

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: false,
    controls: true,
    pager: true,
    auto: true,
    speed: 1000,
    onSlideBefore: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
        console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject);
        $('.active-caption').removeClass('active-caption');
                    $('#bxsliderCaption>ul>li').eq(backwardsCount).addClass('active-caption');
        backwardsCount--;
        if(backwardsCount < 0)
            backwardsCount = 2;
    },
    onSlideNext: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
        console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject);
        $('.active-caption').removeClass('active-caption');
        $('#bxsliderCaption>ul>li').eq(myCount).addClass('active-caption');
        myCount++;
        if(myCount > 2)
            myCount = 0;
    },
    onSliderLoad: function () {
        $('#bxsliderCaption>ul>li').eq(0).addClass('active-caption');
   },

    // http://bxslider.com/options 

});
});
```

Comment: no it's not working, do you have some example? @Bryan Mudge